Get daily count of items which have a start_date and an end_date
I do have tours in a table which do have a start date and an end date, e.g.



id
start_date
end_date




1
2025-06-13
2025-06-13


2
2025-06-12
2025-06-17


3
2025-06-20
2025-06-21


4
2025-05-31
2025-06-02



and so on. What I need now is a count of tours for each day, even when there is no tour at this day. I have a query which has several issues:
SELECT start_date, COUNT(id) AS numberOfTours FROM tour WHERE start_date >= '2025-06-01' AND start_date =< '2025-06-30' GROUP BY start_date ORDER BY start_date;

The 3 I see issues are:

only the start_date is taken into account. As a tour can last for more than one day, this is creating false counts
only a row is created if there is a tour at this day. If a day does not have any tour, no row is created for this day.
Tours that have their start_date prior to the date range are not taken into account (e.g. a tour which starts at 2025-05-31 but ends at 2025-06-02).

the perfect result would look like this:



date
numberOfTours




2025-06-01
1


2025-06-02
1


2025-06-03
0


2025-06-04
0


2025-06-05
0


2025-06-06
0


2025-06-07
0


2025-06-08
0


2025-06-09
0


2025-06-10
0


2025-06-11
0


2025-06-12
1


2025-06-13
2


2025-06-14
1


2025-06-15
1


2025-06-16
1


2025-06-17
1


2025-06-18
0


2025-06-19
0


2025-06-20
1


2025-06-21
1


2025-06-22
0


2025-06-23
0


2025-06-24
0


2025-06-25
0


2025-06-26
0


2025-06-27
0


2025-06-28
0


2025-06-29
0


2025-06-30
0



If it is any help: I do have a day table where each day is represented by a single row.

Generate calendar table then join your data to it.

I actually have a calendar table where each day is represented by a single row. Any hints on correct joining?

The end_date for id 4 was '2026-06-02', which should be '2025-06-02'. I corrected it so the query result is consistent now .

SELECT date, 
        (SELECT COUNT(id) 
        FROM tour 
        WHERE tour.start_date <= day.date 
        AND tour.end_date >= day.date
        ) AS numberOfTours 
FROM day 
WHERE date > '2025-07-01' 
AND date < '2025-07-31' 
ORDER BY date;

quite easy :)
